# Is my proof of the triangle inequality correct?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification

Hello guys it would be a great help if you could look through this proof and point out any errors, I would like to know whether my proof is coherent, and whether it needs more/less detail.

We will be assuming that the general properties of $\mathbb{R}$ and the results of those properties hold, such as that the square root function is increasing, and that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ when $a,b $ are nonnegative.The definition of $|x|$ is as follows, for $x \geq 0, |x|=x,$ for $x<0, |x|=-x$.

Lemmas:

$|x| \geq x$ follows from definition.

We also note that $|x|=\sqrt{(x^2)}$. We prove this by cases. For $x \geq 0$ it is obvious that the equality holds. For $x<0$, since $-x>0$,  $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{(-x)(-x)}=-x=|x|$ . Hence the equality follows.

From the previous lemma it follows that $|x|^2=x^2$

It has to be true that $|xy|=|x||y|$. From the second lemma we know that $|xy|=\sqrt{(xy)^2}=\sqrt{x^2y^2}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{y^2}=|x||y|$

The proof:

$(|a|+|b|)^2=|a|^2+2|a||b|+|b|^2=a^2+2|ab|+b^2 \geq a^2+ 2ab +b^2=(a+b)^2=(|a+b|)^2$

Given that the positive square root function is an increasing function, we take the square root of both sides(this can be done since both sides of the inequality are nonnegative) and obtain $|a|+|b| \geq |a+b|$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: The inequality follows in a much simpler way using the fact that $x \leq |x|$ and $-x \leq |x|$.

Comment: The individual steps are largely correct, but the proof as a whole could use some more context. You seem to prove *some* statements (like $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$), but also seem to assume others *without* proof (like $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, or $\sqrt{\cdot}$ increasing). It is not clear what are the premises you (are allowed to) work with.

Comment: @dvix ive made some changes to my proof, does it work now?

Comment: @Elimination_matrices You might as well add $a^2 \ge 0$ among the assumptions. The triangle inequality comes up at a pretty fundamental level, so if you want to *prove* it then you must be doubly careful with what's been proved *before* that, which you can use.. While your proof is valid now, it is also more involved than it could be, because of those square roots. Suppose for example that you set out to prove the triangle inequality for integers, before even knowing what a real number is. You could prove it as hinted in the 1st comment, but your proof wouldn't work.

Comment: "We will be assuming that the general properties of $\Bbb R$ and the results of those properties hold“. That's a poorly chosen sentence. ALL the known facts about $\Bbb R$, from the very elementary algebraic results, to the calculus theorems, to the deepest analysis theorems are results of those properties. If you "assume the results" you'll have nothing to prove.